# How to animate a rotating, bending flat object

Tags: animation, surface-deform

I'm not that new to blender. I'm having pretty good knowledge in terms of modeling, sculpting texturing. Even some good abilities in animating. But I'm stuck here.

I want to animate a gear, which rotates like gears do, but is bent in the shape of a minimal surface circle, if you know what I mean. I tried to add a bone to each tooth and make it follow a curve. That was actually really close to what I wanted, but the bones made each teeth rotating along their individual z-axis after a full spin. It was also too much effort to get there.

Actually, if I could animate the edges along the bending of the simple deform modifier, it would be absolutely perfect. I'm able to achieve my wanted result if I'm in edit mode, in the deformed gear, and am rotating everything along the z-axis, but obviously, in object mode everything, including the modifier, rotates.

So my question is, if there is to animate a spinning gear in this shape and how I'd get there.

You can find my .blend file right here: https://github.com/Nikku53r/Bended-Gear-animation/blob/main/Zahnrad_def_anim_test.blend

I hope you was able to understand what I wrote. I wasn't sure how I should describe my problem.

Comment: When you rotate the object with the modifier, the already bent shape is rotated, because the modifier applies before the rotation: https://i.imgur.com/lPvdQNv.gif

But what you want to do is to rotate before the modifier, as if you rotated in the Edit Mode? https://i.imgur.com/e4WvMDh.gif Do I get that right?

Comment: As it stands it is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. While files, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, try adding [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post a comment or ask a new question, edit the current post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean like this:

[image]

You just add a bezier curve, bend it as you like. (i just bend it a bit)

Add this modifier to your gear:

[image]

Then animate the rotation of the gear.

[image]

Comment: Wow....simple, but brilliant!!! I just thought too complicated. You made my day :)

Comment: You are welcome! Glad I could help!